# Unable to retrieve the qty updated product value in the cart using Observer

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.4

I am trying to get the cart item value once the qty updated in the Cart page for the specific Item. Have used the below code to get the value, But the event triggered still its showing the old value.

In events.xml I am using the event checkout_cart_update_items_after. Its firing but unable to get the updated data

UpdateCartObserver.php

$items = $observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getItems();

But still  I am able to get only the Item Total value before qty update. I need the cart Item value after qty update. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try using events

- checkout_cart_update_item_complete

  - processItemQty$observer->getItem())

For updates from the mini cart, you may also need

- checkout_cart_update_items_after

  - $observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getItems()

Code

```
public function processItemQty($item) {
        $qty = $item->getQty();
}
```